# Handling routes in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have api with two different versions v1 and v2  both of them have same end points. But the way i handle sessions is different, what will be the clean way of handling routes file and to know which api version user is using. I am using laravel 4.1

Example routes:

```
/v1/getsome/1
/v2/getsome/1
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: that's quite clean. Do you get some error, are stuck somewhere, etc?

Comment: Seems like this could be solved with one controller. I would pass in the version as a parameter. For example: `Route::get('getsome/{id}/{version}/', 'APIController@getsome()');`

Comment: @brokekidweb as i need to call the same controller and function , its just some issue in session only

Comment: @DamienPirsy i don't how to implement routes file , like writing all the routes with v1 and v2 as prefix , i dont want to do like that

Comment: @ezpura edited my comment, would that work? `Route::get('getsome/{id}/{version}/', 'APIController@getsome()')->where('version', '[1-2]+');` would be even more specific.

Answer (score 1):

v1/v2 can easily be a placeholder,so in the future you could change/increase the versioning without breaking the api

```
Route::get('{version}/getSome/{id}', ['as' => 'getstome', 'uses' => 'controller@method');
```

And then you handle the version in the cotnroller's method.

Or you could use a prefix (I'd prefer this), so you don't need to specify the version in your routes:

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'v1'], function(){
  Route::get('getsome/{id}', ....);
};
```

Comment: hey prefixing seem more clean but how to handle different versions with out duplication

Comment: simply how to use multiple prefixes?

Comment: Use the prefixes and add a middleware onto the v2 route which will handle your session issues before it makes it to the controller.

Comment: @user3158900 If you're talking about L5 middlewares, OP's on 4.1

Comment: Then it would be a filter.

Comment: @user3158900 Yeah, I think a filter would be a good solution too. It all boils down to what OP's going to actually implement

Answer (score 0):

Use the version as a parameter in your route, then handle the version in your controller.

```
    Route::get('getsome/{id}/{version}/', 'APIController@getsome()')->where('version', '[1-2]+');
```